# convert a tuple of lists, into one list

Tags: list, haskell, tuples

im trying to convert a tuple of lists to a list but i have not had any success
so i have the function

```
func :: ([a],[a]) -> [a]
```

which gets input such as :

> ( [1,2,3,4], [7,8,9] )

and should return :

> [1,7,2,8,3,9,4]

and i have

```
func (x:xs , y:ys) = x : y : func (xs, ys)
```

what i get as a result is :

> [1,7,2,8,3,9*** Exception: hw2.hs:29:1-54: Non-exhaustive patterns in function func

i know i get this error because lists are not the same size, how do you guys think i can fix this issue

Comment: You would get this error even for two lists of the same size, even for two empty lists. Can you think of a reason why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Non-exhaustive patterns in function func

This indicates the you haven't handled all the cases. Imagine what happens in the following cases:

```
func (x,[]) = ???
func ([],y) = ???
```

Let me know if you need more hints.

Comment: oh wow, i have been on this thing forever and i didnt know if i dont handle those cases it would give me such an error!! i got it now! i learned it the hard way @Sibi